# Retrieve a specific row data in database Android

Tags: java, android, database, listview, android-sqlite

I think I have read pretty much all the answers about this topic without getting the right answer for my case.

I have a list view in one activity called Library. When I click on an item, I would like to retrieve the informations about the clicked item in another activity. I would like these information to be in different field. 
You will probably understand a bit better with my code.

This is the Library activity, on which I have my listview of what I call "tags":

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class InfoTagActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView textTagName;
    TextView textTagId;
    TextView textTagData;
    String tagId;
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "tag_name";
    private static final String TAG_MID = "tag_mid";
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "tag_data";
    static SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    long tag_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_tag);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    //String tagName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    textTagName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagName);
    textTagId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagId);
    textTagData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagInfo);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAllData();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tag_name"));
        textTagName.append(name);
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tag_mid"));
        textTagId.append(id);
        String info = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tag_data"));
        textTagData.append(info);
    }

  }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java :

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper {

private static final String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

// database configuration
// if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

// table configuration
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
private static final String TAG_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
private static final String TAG_NAME = "tag_name";
private static final String TAG_MID = "tag_mid";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "tag_data";

private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

// this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
// but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations
public DatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void insertData (String aTagName, String aTagId, String aTagData) {

    // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(TAG_NAME, aTagName);
    contentValues.put(TAG_MID, aTagId);
    contentValues.put(TAG_DATA, aTagData);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public Cursor getAllData () {

    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}

// this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation

private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Create your tables here

        String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + TAG_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                TAG_NAME + " TEXT, " + TAG_MID + " TEXT, " + TAG_DATA + " TEXT )";

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Database schema upgrade code goes here

        String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
    }
  }
}
```

And InfoTagActivity.java , this is in this activity that I want to get the information about the clicked item :

```
public class InfoTagActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView textTagName;
TextView textTagId;
TextView textTagData;
String tagId;
private static final String TAG_NAME = "tag_name";
private static final String TAG_MID = "tag_mid";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "tag_data";
static SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
long tag_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_tag);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    //String tagName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    textTagName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagName);
    textTagId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagId);
    textTagData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagInfo);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAllData();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tag_name"));
        textTagName.append(name);
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tag_mid"));
        textTagId.append(id);
        String info = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tag_data"));
        textTagData.append(info);
    }

  }
}
```

With the associated activity_info_tag.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tagId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

        android:textColor="@color/main_theme_blue"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tagDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tagIdText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tagIdText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tagDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

        android:textColor="@color/main_theme_blue"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tagDateText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tagDateText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tagDateText"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tagInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

        android:textColor="@color/main_theme_blue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tagDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tagInfoText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tagInfoText"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that by now, when I click on a tag of the list view, it always give me the information about the first tag only. I would like to get the information about the tag on which I clicked instead.
Could someone help me on that ?

Thank you a lot for your answers !

Comment: May this help you http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: When the button is clicked retrieve the primary key of the item clicked and send that data to another activity and using the primary key retrieve the data in the second Activity.

Comment: Can you also post the listview code you have posted the InfoTagActivity twice.

Comment: `String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE MyField = " + somevalue;` somevalue must be included in **'**, if MyField is a string field.

Comment: Thank you but I finally found the solution : I forgot to add the line `this.idInDatabase = getIntent().getLongExtra("tag_id_in_db", -1);`  in the function OnCreate() in the InfoTagActivity.java. This line is used to get the id of the clicked tag to display the good information.